# Scala REPL tab-complete is lying to me?

Tags: scala, webdriver, read-eval-print-loop, sbt, tab-completion

With Scala 2.8.1, SBT 0.7.4, WebDriver HTMLUnit 2.6. In the SBT console REPL ...

```
 scala> e.findElement[tab]

findElement                     findElementById                 findElementByLinkText           findElementByPartialLinkText
findElementByTagName            findElementByXPath              findElements                    findElementsById
findElementsByLinkText          findElementsByPartialLinkText   findElementsByTagName           findElementsByXPath

scala> e.findElementByXPath[tab]

def findElementByXPath(String): org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

scala> e.findElementByXPath("/td[0]")
<console>:12: error: value findElementByXPath is not a member of org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
       e.findElementByXPath("/td[0]")
         ^
```

(`[tab]`s are added by me for the purpose of illustrating tab completion)

So, the REPL tells me that `findElementByXPath(String):WebElement` exists on `e`, but when I invoke it, it's not found. What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here:

```
scala> class X {
     |   def m1 = 1
     |   protected def m2 = 2
     |   private def m3 = 3
     | }
defined class X

scala> class Y extends X {
     |   def m4 = 4
     | }
defined class Y

scala> val x: X = new Y
x: X = Y@12524b0

scala> x.

asInstanceOf   equals         getClass       hashCode       isInstanceOf   m1             m2             m4
notify         notifyAll      toString       wait
```

So, `m2` shows up even though you can't use it because it is protected, and `m4` shows up even though you can't use it (without casting or matching) because `x`'s type is `X`, and `m4` is of class `Y` (the actual `class`, not `type`, of `x`).

Next question: is this intentional? Well, not really, but there are things of higher priority to fix. Patches are welcome, of course. :-)

Comment: I'd like to see the source at least. Where do I go from here ... http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk

Comment: @Sorry, I don't understand your comment. You mean Scala source? From there you go to `src`, and under it you can find various parts of Scala: the compiler, the library, etc. Now that you mention it, I'm not sure where REPL is located... If you go down the compiler path you'll find an `nsc` directory. Its `interactive` and `interpreter` subdirectories seem of particular relevance, as well as some files in `nsc` directory iteself.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to be vague. It was in response to your "Patches are welcome". Meaning I won't commit to that, but I'm interested in reviewing the source to see if I can make head or tail of it. Taking a quick look, I suspect it comes down to def typeMembers in http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala/branches/scala-detach/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/Global.scala - I can't be sure though.

Answer (score 3):

Note that [`org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`](http://webdriver.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) doesn't have these methods, but classes implementing it like [`org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement`](http://webdriver.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitWebElement.html) do.

My best guess is that tab-completion shows all public (or protected; see Daniel's answer) methods of `e`'s *class*, but the type of the variable is `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`, so these methods can't actually be called.

Comment: Yes, you should use e.findElement(By.xpath("/td[0]"))